# Magento error log

Tags: magento-1.9, log

How to fix these error log

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Dailydeals_Block_Widget' in /var/www/html/domain/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('dailydeals/widg...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('dailydeals/widg...', 'c5d44ba0ab3a891...')
#3 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('dailydeals/widg...', 'c5d44ba0ab3a891...')
#4 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(77): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#10 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/html/domain/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/domain/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Comment: did you remove `Dailydeals` this module

Comment: Yes i remove module from file & Db also

Comment: did you remove file from `app/ec/modules`

Comment: Please ensure your `home` page or any other cms/static block content didn't have `dailydeals` entries. Also clear your `Magento` cache. If compilation is enable then recompile it.

Comment: @JayeshPatel ididn't use any static block

Comment: @QaisarSatti i remove there also

Comment: you are calling this block in somewhere in phtml file find that remove from there too..

Comment: @QaisarSatti, you are correct and @LearningMagento also try to find `dailydeals` inside you layout xml files

Comment: Flush the cache storage

Comment: LearningMagento and @Baby in Magento seems same person with different user name. am i correct ?

Comment: No he is different person but we are working same company

Comment: Ok.You both have used "totaltoys" reference in your question that's y

Comment: Oh sorry we will change it

Comment: i delete all file phtml xml css js delete cache folder also still it's showing

Answer (score 1):

Find in your `app/etc/modules` folder some xml file which name ends on `Dailydeals.xml` (for example `Blabla_Dailydeals.xml`)

Edit this file and put there

```
        <active>false</active>
```

**Upd.1**

Try to search in your app/design folder for the word `dailydeals` in layout xml files. Most probably e.g. in `local.xml` you forgot to remove it.

Or maybe you have CMS page with such block type which need to be disabled or removed.

**Upd.2**

Create sql dump of your magento DB with following command:

```
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE > /path/to/file/dump.sql
```

Then search in this file for the word `dailydeals` and show us where did you find it.

Comment: i already delete that module from my site itself

Comment: updated..............